# Testing generated crystal report with Coded UI

Tags: crystal-reports, coded-ui-tests

One of my test cases requires me to test a Crystal Report generated by the application. I am using Coded UI. The UIMap recorder detects the whole page in the report as an UITextItem, but the text in the report is in some child controls (I can click on them, but the recorder does not detect them).

The asnwers to this question [Unit testing a report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555805/unit-testing-a-report) explain that I can only export the data into another file, and test against that. The answers are from 2009. I was hoping that maybe soemthing has improved in the meantime.

Is there a way to test the valeus in a generated Crystal Reports report using Coded UI, besides exporting it to another file and testing against that file?

**EDIT per AdrianHHH's comment:**

When moving the arrows, it appears to iterate through the controls in the report. It shows something like: SectionX -> UIFieldTextX (where X is a number, of order I think). All the elements have the field *DisplayText* empty.

All elements have the *ControlType* set to *Text*.

Comment: What does Coded UI's assertion builder tool see of the controls? Having selected a control (so it is enclosed by a blue box) you can use the four arrows to change the selected item.

Comment: @AdrianHHH please see my edit.

Comment: Your update tells nothing useful. Did you try the down-arrow from each control? What was shown when the down-arrow is greyed out? Are the reports made using custom controls? Know that custom controls need to be written to support Coded UI. Perhaps you need to ask the suppliers of Crystal whether it can be tested with Coded UI.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Unfortunately nothing useful is shown. Only the basic properties from Control Specific and Generic sections. There is nothing useful in the properties, only control type, no display text. I think, Crystal Reports wasn't built with Coded UI support in mind.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create or use an existing UFL (Crystal Reports User Function Library).
Existing UFLs (see list [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl)) provide functions that allow a Crystal report formula to write a value from a Crystal report to a text file, ini file, registry, spreadsheet, or database. 
So you could use this as a mechanism to interrogate a value in a Crystal report.

Comment: I think this is the best option. But, I need to confirm with my client if they are willing to recreate the report and include the UFL.